# How to create a row span in yii2 gridview?

Tags: html, css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My gridview wants to implement rowsapn to two columns, Offical MOU sites and Official MOU sites > 2700. I want some logic to bring value to this two columns.

What is the best way to implement this in Yii2?

[image]

I try this code

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'category',
            'value' => function ($model) use ($dataProvider) {
                $count = $dataProvider->query->where(['category' => $model->category])->count();
                return $model->category . ' (Count: ' . $count . ')';
            },
        ],
        'name',
        'price',
    ],
]);
```

But this is not what I really want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement rowspan for two columns, `Official MOU sites` and `Official MOU sites > 2700`, you can achieve this by customizing the GridView in Yii2. You need to modify the columns array and use the contentOptions property to set the rowspan based on your logic.

```
use yii\grid\GridView;

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'], // Adjust styling as needed
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'category',
            'value' => function ($model) use ($dataProvider) {
                return $model->category;
            },
            'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) use ($dataProvider) {
                $count = $dataProvider->query->where(['category' => $model->category])->count();
                return ['rowspan' => $count + 1]; // Add 1 for the main row
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'], // Adjust styling as needed
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'price',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'], // Adjust styling as needed
        ],
    ],
]);
```